# Two Mice not working after screen lock

Tags: lubuntu, mouse, screen, lock

I have written a Perl script allowing the user to use simultaneously two
mice. One right-handed and the other left-handed. The script works. The problem is that after returning from screen lock, both mice become left-handed (which is the config I've chosen in mouse configs). 
The linux distro I have is Lubuntu 16.04.2 LTS

The script (twomice.pl) is as follows:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

# print "Two Mice\n";
# one left-handed and the other right-handed: cool!

# enter strings from command "xinput list"
my $leftDevice  = "Mouse";
my $rightDevice = "MOUSE";

my $leftHandedOptions  = "1 2 3";
my $rightHandedOptions = "3 2 1";

my $infole = `/usr/bin/xinput list | grep $leftDevice`;
my $infori = `/usr/bin/xinput list | grep $rightDevice`;

my $beginPart = "id=";
my $endPart = "\t";
$infole =~ /$beginPart(.*?)$endPart/; $infole = $1;
$infori =~ /$beginPart(.*?)$endPart/; $infori = $1;

my $commandWords = "/usr/bin/xinput set-button-map";
my $leftMouseCfg = $commandWords . " " . $infole . " " . $leftHandedOptions; 
my $rightMouseCfg = $commandWords . " " . $infori . " " . $rightHandedOptions;

#print $leftMouseCfg . "\n";
#print $rightMouseCfg ."\n";

system($leftMouseCfg);
system($rightMouseCfg);
```

Comment: disabling the 'gnome settings daemon' on startup seemed to have solved the issue

Comment: I'm glad you were able to figure it out! If you have the time and inclination, consider entering that solution as an answer - yes, you can answer your own question and mark that as a solution - this helps the community in case future people have a similar question, and that way this question will no longer appear in the unanswered queues.

Answer (score 1):

disabling the 'gnome settings daemon' on startup solved the issue